# Recreate a job application account due to too many unsuccessful applications?

Tags: recruitment, applications

I have been applying to several jobs via an application tracking system (ie Jobvite, directly from the employer's website, where I upload a tailored resume and cover letter for each position). I have an account with about 10 applications, most of which have not responded, and about three of which are labeled "rejected". I showed this to my friend, who recommended that I create a new account using a new email because recruiters can check one's profile and reject applicants who have lots of rejections.

So, I wonder if I should create a new account to start with a "fresh" history?

I am applying to software engineering/developer jobs after a career change, so I am trying to get an entry-level job. I have not been successful as I have minimal relevant experience, although I am constantly improving my abilities. I would prefer to be as genuine as possible, although I question the judgments a recruiter would make based on the status of my applications over the last three months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well creating a new account is one option you have.  However if your name is the same and your work history is the same or very similar you run a real risk of being detected and removed from the site completely if it is against their Terms of service (and with out knowing the specific site I am willing to wager a large sum that it is against their terms).

But even if your attempt is not detected you are still facing the same problem you had when you first started appling, **your resume is not attracting the attention of people making interview decisions.**

So the first thing I would recommend is to review your resume and see how you can improve it.  One place that can be a great help in this arena is a consulting company.  They are highly experienced seeing what works on resume's to get successful results.  They may actually be your best bet for getting an entry level position as well.

Once you get your resume improved you should up load it to a different site.  Chances are the majority of people who are going to see your resume on the original site have already looked at it and rejected it.  So go to a different site and look for a new audience.

Comment: Either that, or the application tracking system isn't attracting the attention of the people making interview decision... and you might need to think about another way to publicize yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about a website where you fill in an online form to create your profile/resume/CV. That's fine if the "one size fits all" format actually fits you, but it may not be the best approach for you.

Since you're trying to make a career change, and don't have a lot of relevant experience, you may be better off preparing a resume/CV and submitting it to companies in the old-fashioned way. This will give you an opportunity to present your experience in the best possible light.

For example, you might want to add a "career objective" at the beginning of your CV, explaining that you are looking for a career change and want a position as a software engineer. Also explain this in the cover letter/email, perhaps in a bit more detail. (Why do you want to make this career change? What makes you think you will like software development?) Career objective statements aren't required in a CV, but they can be useful in this case.

You can also try to find ways to describe your previous experience that will highlight skills that are relevant to your new career. For example, have you had to write instructions for people on how to do something? Did you troubleshoot problems (not necessarily software, perhaps process or customer satisfaction issues). Have you had to follow or implement a process? Did you lead a team?